# How to See The Attribute Result Of Geometric Network Trace

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geometric-network

Running ArcMap 10.4.1 I can trace a geometric Network and see the Graphical returns of Junctions and Edges inside the network but can you please let me know How/ Where I can see the Attributes return from the Trace?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the layer is selectable, run trace, open attribute table, view selected records,  view data and statistics. 
From the doc [online help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/geometric-networks/about-tracing-on-geometric-networks.htm)

> You can specify which layers are selected when performing a trace operation. From the Selection menu in ArcMap, you can specify which layers can and cannot be selected. When ArcMap returns the results of a trace operation as a selection set, the settings you specify in the Selection menu are used to determine which features should be included in the selection set returned by the trace.